# How to get input and call a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, input

Hi guys I am currently learning javascript and I got stuck on one problem. 
I am trying to make simple function which will convert from celsius to Fahrenheit.
I don't know how to call the function :( How do I get input so that input can start the function?

Here is the code:

```
var input = prompt("Input temperature in celsius");

function temp (input);

function temp (c){
  var result = 0;
  result = c * 1.8 + 32
return result; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply call it by typing `temp(input)` and nothing else. So for example if you want to store the value, you do

```
var tempInF = temp(input);
```

Or to show a pupup/alert farenheit with full code:

```
var input = prompt("Input temperature in celsius");

alert(temp(input));

function temp (c){
  var result = 0;
  result = c * 1.8 + 32
return result; }
```

Please see the **Function Return** section in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.